# Richfaces enable on only one page

Tags: java, jsf, configuration, richfaces

I worked hard on this problem but no way to find a solution.

I juste wan't to enable richfaces for one and only one HTML page.

Why ?
Because I use RichFaces on only one page.
Moreover I'm losing precious time on each others during the page loading due to JavaScript code that I don't use.

=> This code is add on each of my pages. I just wan't it on my page "helloRichfaces.jsf"

`<link class="component" href="/myProject/a4j/s/3_3_1.GAorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/basic_classes.xcss/DATB/eAF7sqpgb-jyGdIAFrMEaw__.jsf" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><link class="component" href="/myProject/a4j/s/3_3_1.GAorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/css/extended_classes.xcss/DATB/eAF7sqpgb-jyGdIAFrMEaw__.jsf" media="rich-extended-skinning" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /><script type="text/javascript">window.RICH_FACES_EXTENDED_SKINNING_ON=true;</script><script src="/myProject/a4j/g/3_3_1.GAorg/richfaces/renderkit/html/scripts/skinning.js.jsf" type="text/javascript"></script><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Good luck !

Comment: What are first few line of your nor-richfaces page? Do you use facelets in your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the tag lib you are using on every page

**<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%> 
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%> 
<%@taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/a4j" prefix="a4j"%> 
<%@taglib uri="http://richfaces.org/rich" prefix="rich"%>**

Remove the rich faces tag lib and use only

**<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" prefix="f"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" prefix="h"%>**

Answer (score 1):

These looks like artefacts related to the [Skinnability](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/ArchitectureOverview.html#Skinnability) support. Try disabling it in your `web.xml`:

```
  <context-param>
    <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
    <param-value>NONE</param-value>
  </context-param>
```